# How can we tell the difference between an actual and apparent type?

Tags: c++

If you have a class hierarchy and you'd like to determine what could be actual types that an object is pointing to, is the answer just any subclass of the object?  If the object is an abstract class, can you still declare a pointer of that object that's apparent and actual type is that object?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: Why would you want to know all the possibilities? All that matters is that it supports the base class's interface. In the rare case you do need to know, there's `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @Pubby does dynamic_cast work for base to derived, or only for derived to base?

Comment: Please make your questions more precise than this, and illustrate with an example if possible.

Comment: @BobJohn It's only for base to derived.

Comment: He obviously means the *most derived type* of the object pointed to by a base-class pointer.  First, as Pubby says, it's usually a sign of bad design to depend on this type: it encourages code to use `switch` or `if` statements to handle "every possible" derived class, and that code can easily break if more classes are added in future. It is possible to get the type using `dynamic_cast<>`, but only if the base class, or a superclass of it, contains 1 or more virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the type of an object (derived or base) at run time, you can do so with the RTTI typeid operator.

Comment: But you really don;t want to know.